# Adding task dependencies in .sbt file

Tags: scala, build, dependencies, sbt

In my build.sbt file I have two custom tasks:

```
TaskKey[Unit]("aaa") := {
  println("aaa")
} 

TaskKey[Unit]("bbb") := {
  println("bbb")
}
```

How do I add a dependency between them? For example, I want `aaa` to depend on `bbb`.

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks

To depend on the side effect of some tasks without using their values and without doing additional work, use dependOn on a sequence of tasks. The defining task key (the part on the left side of <<=) must be of type Unit, since no value is returned.

```
unitTask <<= Seq(stringTask, sampleTask).dependOn
```

To add dependencies to an existing task without using their values, call dependsOn on the task and provide the tasks to depend on. For example, the second task definition here modifies the original to require that string-task and sample-task run first:

```
intTask := 4

intTask <<= intTask.dependsOn(stringTask, sampleTask)
```

Comment: I get the following error: `error: not found: value intTask intTask := 4`

Comment: The error seems to be similar to: http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/06f0bece9e60e05b , but they don't describe how to handle dependencies.

Comment: you need to define the TaskKey. See the documentation at that link. It explains how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

```
val aaa = TaskKey[Unit]("aaa", "First")
val bbb = TaskKey[Unit]("bbb", "Second")

bbb := { println("bbb") }
aaa := bbb map { _ => println("aaa") }
```

Comment: `illegal start of simple expression val aaa = TaskKeyUnit`

Comment: I meant full build definition rather than .sbt file.